# How to figure out what is wrong when NEP on Presenter.onCreateViewHolder in leanback was thrown

Tags: android-tv, leanback

After data arrived form server I do simply thing:

```
    private fun updateItemsOnUi(items: List<Item>) {
        val listRowAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(ItemPresenterSelector())
        val header = HeaderItem(0, "")
        for (item in items) listRowAdapter.add(item)
        rowsAdapter.add(ItemListRow(header, listRowAdapter, null))
    }
```

I rewrite simple example with detail screen. And after that I get such exception, but there is no point to my code so how to investigate what I was doing wrong?

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.leanback.widget.Presenter$ViewHolder androidx.leanback.widget.Presenter.onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ItemBridgeAdapter.java:352)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.getViewForPosition(GridLayoutManager.java:1085)
        at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager$2.createItem(GridLayoutManager.java:1613)
        at androidx.leanback.widget.SingleRow.appendVisibleItems(SingleRow.java:113)
        at androidx.leanback.widget.Grid.appendVisibleItems(Grid.java:397)
        at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.appendVisibleItems(GridLayoutManager.java:1934)
        at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:2291)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case it was not registered class presenter in ClassPresenterSelector.

I had to add line:

```
rowPresenterSelector.addClassPresenter(ItemListRow::class.java,  ListRowPresenter())
```

See full code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setupUi()
    setupEventListeners()
}

private fun setupUi() {

        val rowPresenterSelector = ClassPresenterSelector()
        //this line was needed!
        rowPresenterSelector.addClassPresenter(ItemListRow::class.java,  ListRowPresenter())

        rowsAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(rowPresenterSelector)
        adapter = rowsAdapter
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a common mistake when using PresenterSelector (you need to specify the types in addClassPresenter() method), unfortunately Leanback is not really friendly explaining what exactly is going on, but that is the usual case for Leanback, isn't